# Ignoring specific JS errors by matching text

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

In my hosts file and ad blocker, I have a domain and a file to be ignored by my computer - to prevent some problems (I'm ignoring api.mixpanel.com to not trigger tracking on my local machine and I'm ignoring print.css on all websites because Chrome for some reason injects it to the screen as well as print media). Problem is, they cause 2 JS errors by default, as the following screenshot shows:

[image: Screenshot of Errors]

This is pretty useless and it confuses me when confronting JS errors sometimes. Is there a way to match, for example, `/^GET (.+)/print\.css$/i` and not include it in the error log on the Chrome console? Or would the best solution be to just find the code where it calls those and try/catch there?

Comment: Doesn't look like a "JS error", rather just a networking one. That is, those have no relation with JavaScript whatsoever. You could monkeypatch it with some JS hackery in the form of an extension, but that's a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no. Especially as those two errors in the console are not Javascript errors, but resource errors (Chrome couldn't access the two resources).

However, you can [filter what you see in the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#filtering_console_output).